# Which one is bubble sort?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

The first:

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
  for(int j=n-1; j>i;j--)
    if(a[j] < a[j-1])
        swap(a[j], a[j-1]);
```

or the second:

```
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
  for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    if(a[j] < a[i])
        swap(a[j],a[i]);
```

or third version:

```
int temp, i, j = 0;
    boolean swaped = true;

    while (swaped) {
        swaped = false;
        j++;
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length - j; i++){
            if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = temp;
                swaped = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Someone say the first and someone say the second. So which one is right? Someone say the second is interchange sort. Many book say bubble sort is the third version, but many people called the first version is bubble sort. Any comment?

Comment: The third version - is kinda strange.  Does it even sort?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: It's a common optimization for a bubble sort

Comment: Guess I stopped using it too long ago :)  I wonder why?

Comment: Check Wikipedia on [Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) and [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) and [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).  After review, I think the first corresponds to an insertion sort (the decrementing loop is indicative of that if Wikipedia is to be trusted) while the second is a bubble sort.  I'm sure that none of them is a selection sort; there is more swapping going on than in a selection sort.

Comment: You should not alter the question after so many people have already given answers.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler the idea of bubble sort is swap 2 element "nearly" for put the largest or smallest to top or bot of array, the idea of the second is different so i think it is not bubble sort.

Answer (score 7):

The first version is the bubble sort, because it's comparing each pair of adjacent items.

The second version is a selection sort because `a[i]` ends up being the smallest item in the unsorted right portion of the array after each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Are you sure that any of those is a selection sort?  I thought that a selection sort went through the unsorted section of the array, finding the smallest element and moving it to the start of the unsorted section, then decreasing the size of the unsorted section by one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's not quite the same. The state is the same as selection sort for each outer iteration but there's some extra redundant swaps. It's still finding the smallest element but it's swapping the smallest found so far multiple times instead of once at the end. I thought it could be some bubble sort variant but I think bubble sort requires swapping adjacent elements.

Comment: There's an element of "I'm not quite sure why I'm bothered" (since they're all slow and not singularly useful), but there's also an element of "I'd like it to be right".  You'll see in comments to the main question, that I think the first is insertion sort, the second a bubble sort, and the third a modified bubble sort.  I still think none is a selection sort; see the Wikipedia articles cited in my comments to the question.  (I also got it wrong in the first of those comments — I'm not claiming perfection here!)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As for the first algorithm, the idea of the insertion sort requires inserting an item within the already sorted portion which the first algorithm doesn't do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i agree with fgb, the fist can't be insertion sort. It is bubble sort  because it swapping adjacent elements. The idea of insertion sort is we keep the left part of the array sorted and take element from the right and insert it in the left part at its proper place. Like when you play game of cards each player get 13 cards, player keeps them in the sorted order in his hand for his ease. To do that player select 1 card unsorted and put it into the middle(left, right) list cards sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I tested both your code snippets on an actual array using Java in IntelliJ.  Both versions generated an array in ascending sorted order.

Here is the array I used:

```
int[] a = {1, 9, 3, 5, 4, 2, 8, 6, 7};
```

And here is the output from the two versions:

**Version 1**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Version 2**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The first version looks like a standard bubble sort, while the second version appears to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

1.The first:

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
  for(int j=n-1; j>i;j--)
    if(a[j] < a[j-1])
        swap(a[j], a[j-1]);
```

This is **Bubble** Sort

2.the second:

```
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
  for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    if(a[j] < a[i])
        swap(a[j],a[i]);
```

It is **selection** sort

Even though at first glance it will give an impression that its a reversed implementation of bubble sort, it is not. It is **selection** sort as other user pointed out already

3.third version:

```
int temp, i, j = 0;
    boolean swaped = true;

    while (swaped) {
        swaped = false;
        j++;
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length - j; i++){
            if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = temp;
                swaped = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is in fact, **enhanced bubble sort**
This will improve the best case scenario